# Running building wire across 2x4s of drop ceiling

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

Just bought a house built in 1902. I want to add a new light fixture in the dining room that requires running 12/2 cable to it since there is no existing fixture.

From putting an endoscope in the ceiling it looks like a drop ceiling was added at some point (I think?). It also looks like there is a gap between the 2x4s and the original ceiling.

[image]
(from top to bottom - original ceiling, gap, 2x4, sheetrock)

Obviously, it would be easiest to run the wire for my light fixture in the gap rather than drill holes through the 2x4s.

So, my question is - can I run the wire in this gap or do I need to drill holes through the 2x4s? Will I be violating any codes by running the wire through the gaps of the drop ceiling?

Comment: just curious... what light requires 12 gauge wiring (20Amp/2400 Watts)?? unless there are other things on the circuit.

Comment: Almost all the breakers in my house are 20 amp - don't ask me why, it was like that when we bought it :)

Comment: just think about this -are all the wiring on the 20A breaker 12 gauge?  if not, you might be safer going down to 15A breakers.  Often home owners would throw in 20A breakers when the 15A would keep tripping - which it was supposed to do.

Comment: Fair point, that's something I'll consider.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can but it might not be as easy as you think, unless you can cut a hole large enough to be able to get above the 2x4 and push it to where it needs to be. Also just be sure the old ceiling doesn't flex and pinch the romex.

Good luck